# NTLM is not working with Http.sys of ASP.NET Core 2.1 on .NET48 with https and wildcard certificate when accessing from same machine

Tags: https, asp.net-core-2.1, ntlm, .net-4.8, httpsys

So the NTLM authentication does not work with Http.sys of ASP.NET Core 2.1 on .NET48 with https when accessed from the browser on the same machine the server is running on. Nevertheless it works when accessed from any other machine.

Screenshot of network requests:
[image]

The wildcard certificate is issued for example to ***.mycompany.com** and the url used for hosting with Http.sys is **https://server01.mycompany.com:443/app**.

However username/password does work in all settings.

Has anyone encountered the same problem? Or does have a solution to this problem?

**Edit:** Typos, screenshot added.

**Edit 2:** I have created an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28088) at Github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the "full computer name", which can be seen in Control Panel\System and Security\System.
Instead of **server01.mycompany.com** it was actually **server01.graz.mycompany.com** and the url didn't match that. Also a new TLS wildcard certificate for ***.graz.mycompany.com** is necessary.